# Cheap 6x6 (or better) USB 2.0 matrix switch

Tags: usb

I am looking for a device which is able to route at least six arbitrary USB 2.0 inputs to at least six arbitrary USB 2.0 outputs (6x6 matrix). It should have an interface like ethernet or RS-232 to control the routing. There should be *no device emulation* like KVM switches do, the simpler the better.

So far the only device I found which meets my needs is the 8x8 matrix switch [Smart-AVI MU-88](http://smartavi.com/mu-88/).

Unfortunately, the price of the device is far too much for the budget of my (private) project. Are there any cheaper devices with the same or at least nearly the same features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with a combination of the following devices:

- Extron SMX 44 USB
- Extron SW4 USB Plus

The price was high but still okay buying used devices.

It turned out the device emulation (keyboard and mouse) is not a problem in my case, it even helped!